# Rake + Sidekiq + Model Logging output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, passenger, sidekiq

I have a rake task that starts a worker `MyWorker.perform_async('Aname')`.

```rb
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :retry => false, :queue => :hello

  def perform(name)
        Model.find_by_name(name).do_stuff
  end
end
```

Now logging produced inside `do_stuff` does not show up in any log file or I cannot seem to find it?

```
class Model
  def do_stuff
    #Where can I see the output?
    puts "Test puts!!!"
    logger.info "Test logger!!!"
  end
end
```

Comment: you `Model` class is a bit stipped to much :) is the logger function a custom logger or just the Rails logger?

Comment: I tried Rails.logger, but whatever you suggest.